# (XAMPP) MySql Console to phpmyadmin

Tags: phpmyadmin, xampp

So I'm using the MySql with the console but im not so used to it. so I'd like to display it in phpmyadmin using my xampp. I can see the databases but i cant open it there is an error please see image below. I hope some one knows this or anything i am doing wrong thanks[image: ![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LBjQT.png)

[image]

Comment: do you have the needed privileges ? are you logged in as a `root` ?

Comment: i just typed in the console mysql -u root. In the console everything is working but in phpmyadmin i cant do anything.

Comment: The console is a lot simpler application than phpmyadmin and a completely separate one. Phpmyadmin itself uses a database within a mysql server to store its configuration. The error message complains that one of these tables is not found. Probably you need to reinstall phpmyadmin to fix the issue. But this question is not really about software development...

Comment: @Shadow Please have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/help/product-support

Comment: @MarcDelisle Please have a look at what questions are considered on-topic in the first place.

Comment: @Shadow I did (http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic); how about "software tools commonly used by programmers" ?

Comment: @MarcDelisle phpmyadmin is a mysql admin tool, not an sw development tool.

Comment: @Shadow You are twisting my words, I said it's a software tool commonly used by programmers (at least by some programmers of web sites). Where do you see "sw development tool" in the reference I gave you? Also there are 8886 questions tagged "phpmyadmin" here.

Comment: @MarcDelisle "software tools commonly used by programmers; **and is
a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development**". If you quote, then pls quote fully, not just any particular part that supports your point! Furthermore, you can use Excel for sw development, you have thousands of questions tagged as excel, while nobody would consider the installation of excel an SO worthy question. Same should apply to a db management tool.

Comment: @Shadow I still don't see "software development tool" in the quote you give. As for "software development", I assume that building a web application can be considered software development, and managing a database is related to building a web app. As for you suggestion of "installation", it's you who suggested that in your reply above. My answer points to a configuration problem.

Comment: @MarcDelisle And if you document your code in Word, then Word is also used for sw development, so if you have a problem with installing and configuring it, then ask it on SO, right? The P clearly installed phpmyadmin and tried to use it and cannot. So, sg went wrong in the installation. This problem is not unique to sw development because phpmyadmin is not an sw development tool.

Comment: @Shadow I'll stop right here because we don't agree on the definition of a software development tool.

Answer (score 0):

There is a mismatch between the "phpMyAdmin configuration storage" directives in config.inc.php and your actual tables. Start by commenting out the line that mentions pmadb, then close and reopen phpMyAdmin in your browser. All should be fine now but to benefit from additional features, see http://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/setup.html#phpmyadmin-configuration-storage.

Comment: i tried but nothing happened but thanks for the suggestion

Comment: What do you mean "nothing happened" ?

Comment: Additionally, this seems to be a common problem with a recent XAMPP release, other posters have found that downgrading their XAMPP versions is an alternative solution.